# Заполнение значений массива в строку, а не в столбец

Tags: winforms, listview, c++-cli

Может ли *ListView* заполнять значения не в столбец, а в строки?

Ситуация следующая:
Мне нужно заполнить значения так,как показано на рисунке:

[image: таблица]

Например начальное условие 0,01 и оно заканчивается на граничном 1,1 и вот мои i1,i2,i3,i4 и нужно заполнить значения в строку (от начального до конечного).

Как добавлять столбцы через цикл уже знаю:

```
int kolst =10;
listView1->Columns->Add("Начальные условия", -2, HorizontalAlignment::Right);
for(int i = 1;i<kolst+1;i++)
 {
  listView1->Columns->Add("i + " + i, -2, HorizontalAlignment::Left);//Нумерация столбцов
 }
listView1->Columns->Add("Граничные условия", -2, HorizontalAlignment::Left);
```

А вот как заполнить значения именно по строкам не понятно.
Начальные и граничные условия и их выражения я заполнил как надо, осталось только заполнить выражения из массива в строку, а не в столбец(i1,i2,i3,i4).
То есть под каждым i1,i2 у меня должно быть значение массива.
Как можно это сделать?

Что пытался сделать:
Я подставлял в цикл `Items.Add,Columns.Add`, но в строчку не выводилось.

Comment: Какую GUI библиотеку Вы используете? В c++ нет никаких `ListView`.

Comment: @alexolut  
использую среду Microsoft Visual Studio,Windows Forms

Comment: В таком случае, это уже не `c++`, а `c++/cli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забудьте заменить значения для начальных и конечных столбцов (InitialValue & RangeBound):

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   System::Windows::Forms::ListView^ listView1;

    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        int kolst = 10;

        this->listView1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListView());
        this->SuspendLayout();

        this->listView1->Columns->Add("Начальные условия", -2, HorizontalAlignment::Right);
        for(int i = 1;i<kolst+1;i++)
        {
            this->listView1->Columns->Add("i + " + i, -2, HorizontalAlignment::Left);//Нумерация столбцов
        }
        this->listView1->Columns->Add("Граничные условия", -2, HorizontalAlignment::Left);

        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItemInitial = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"InitialValue"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"q1"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"q2"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"q3"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"q4"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"q5"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"q6"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"q7"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"q8"));
        System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItemRangeBound = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(L"RangeBound"));

        this->listView1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  >(10) {listViewItemInitial, listViewItem1, listViewItem2, 
            listViewItem3, listViewItem4, listViewItem5, listViewItem6, listViewItem7, listViewItem8, listViewItemRangeBound});
    }
}
```